# Javascript new Date() not working...sometimes

Tags: javascript

I can't figure this out for the life of me. The below code does not give me the day of the week, but instead give me the 'Choose date' option:

```js
var year = '21';
var month = '4';
var date = '3';

var dow = new Date(parseInt(year), parseInt(month) - 1, parseInt(date)).getDay() || 'Choose date';

console.log(dow);
```

If I change the month to '3', it works fine. In fact, it works for the vast majority of combinations I have tried. Another combination that doesn't work is year = '21', month = '10', date = '2'. What am I missing? I'm trying this in Chrome. Please, help!

Comment: This: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date#syntax - read about the year. I doubt you want 1921.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sunday is considered the first day of the week and therefore if you use `getDay()` on a date object representing a sunday the output will be `0`. The result of `0 || 'Choose date'` is `'Choose date'`

```js
var date = new Date("2021-01-31T00:00:00.000Z");
console.log(date);
console.log(date.getDay());
console.log(date.getDay() || "Choose Date");
```

In case you were wondering why the result of `0 || "text"` is not `0`, it's because `0` is considered a falsy and the result of `falsy || else` is always the second part.

You can check this [page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) to see which values are considered falsy (all the values that are not in this group are considered truthy)

Comment: @CherryPoppins What I don't understand is, when is "Choose date" valid?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve though.

If you want to get the day of the week, why do you add || 'Choose date'; at then end?

If the problem is that you dont understand why it returns 'Choose date', I am explaining.

You can use || as a default operator... if the first part is falsy (and 0 is falsy) it will run the code after the || and return its value.

In your code getDay() will return 0 for any Sunday... and it will evaluate the second part returning it...

Comment: This was just a quick example. I need 'choose date' if the date is not valid. My issue was I wasn't thinking about how 0 would lose out to the string.